# Unable to access docker container Socket hang up error

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, get, postman

I have successfully built and started the docker container, it is running perfectly, but when I try to access it [`End point url 0.0.0.0:6001`] I am getting a "socket hang up" error

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:6001/
Error: socket hang up

Request Headers
  User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
  Accept: */*
  Postman-Token: <token>
  Host: 0.0.0.0:6001
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  Connection: keep-alive
```

Earlier it was working fine but when I removed the containers and images and rebuild it then I started getting this error

I am using `Postman` to make `GET` request and I also tried Web browser

Can anyone tell me whats the problem

**--Update--**

[Docker File](https://pastebin.com/3BvkHzn3)

Creating containers

```
# Create Virtual Network
$ sudo docker network create network1 
# Using custom network as there are multiple containers 
# which communicate with each other

# Create Containers
$ sudo docker build -t form_ocr:latest .
$ sudo docker run -d -p 6001:5000 --net network1 --name form_ocr form_ocr
```

`netstat` command output

```
$ netstat -nltp 
...
tcp6       0      0 :::6001                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

`docker container inspect` output

```
$ sudo docker container inspect <container-id>
```

[output](https://pastebin.com/cVgSxBp4)

`docker ps` output

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        COMMAND             CREATED        STATUS           PORTS                    NAMES
835e8cb11eee        form_ocr     "python3 app.py"    16 hours ago   Up 40 seconds    0.0.0.0:6001->5000/tcp   form_ocr
```

Comment: Any luck with this problem? I am facing the same issue here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878862/dockerized-version-vs-non-dockerized-version-of-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try localhost:6001 not internet address

You can also try any of your system local ipaddress , you find ipaddress  by typing ifconfig or ipconfig if you are in linux or windows respectively

Comment: I tried `localhost:6001` and `local_ip:6001` but same error appears

Comment: could you goto postman>settings>proxy and see if proxy is set ? try removing it or adding currect proxy .

Comment: are you sure the serveice is exposed to host ip ? did you try accessing it in browser and verify the service is indeed exposed thtorugh host

Comment: service is not accessible in browser also

Comment: How are you starting docker container please add the command

Comment: Hello @PDHide I have updated the post with more details please have a look

Comment: could yopu check docker ps and add the output

Comment: I have added `docker ps` output in the post

Comment: Can you try turning of firewall in your docker host system and try if. You can connect ?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with fastapi container

Make sure your app is listening on 0.0.0.0 within the container

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Just add this in main.ts, where you listen to the port:

```
await app.listen(6001, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Listening on port: 6000`));
```

Add the '0.0.0.0' , it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with fast-API server inside the container:

To fix let the fast-API server bi running on the host ="0.0.0.0", when you use the `uvicorn.run` method because by default the host "127.0.0.1" will be used.

For me this worked:

`uvicorn.run(self, host="0.0.0.0", port=port)`